# How to filter data using Elastic Search by adding two fields as a condition？

Tags: elasticsearch

## How to filter data using Elastic Search by adding two fields as a condition？

**Like the following sql statement**

```sql
select * from hello where hello.a + hello.b > 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Elastic search gives best performance when things are precomputed. If sum was already in index then a simple range query would give result.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "range": {
                  "sum_field": {
                    "gte": 10
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For your current scenario, you need to use [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html)

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "doc['field1'].value + doc['field2'].value > params.limit",
                        "lang": "painless",
                        "params": {
                          "limit": 10
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

script is slow it will run for each document , compute sum and filter result.